# Using existing Singleton objects for Autowire injection

Tags: java, spring, annotations, singleton

We use singleton service classes in our application:

```
public class LevelApprovalServiceImpl extends BaseBusinessServiceImpl implements LevelApprovalService {

    /** There's one and only one instance of this class */
    private static final LevelApprovalServiceImpl INSTANCE = new LevelApprovalServiceImpl();

    /**
     * Constructor is private, use getInstance to get
     * an instance of this class
     */
    private LevelApprovalServiceImpl() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns the singleton instance of this class.
     *
     * @return  the singleton instance of this class.
     */
    public static LevelApprovalServiceImpl getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

We recently upgraded Spring to Spring 5 and have started using the @Autowired annotation in our controllers:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/approvals")
public class ApprovalRestController extends BaseRestController {
    @Autowired
    transient private LevelApprovalService levelApprovalService;  
}
```

The problem is that due to this, our web application currently has 2 instances of every singleton service: the singleton we created ourselves and the singleton created by Spring. autowiring. We'd rather this not be the case and have a single singleton instance for everything.

Is there a way to tell Spring to use the getInstance() method of the singleton while still using Spring annotations to wire things together? Not every service is used in the Spring frontend, so we need to have Spring use our singleton instance instead of the other way around, and we'd rather not have to switch to xml-based configuration or start using a configuration file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a `@Bean` method in one of your `@Configuration` classes.

```
@Configuration
public class Configuration {

    @Bean
    public LevelApprovalService getLevelApprovalService() {
        return LevelApprovalServiceImpl.getInstance();
    }

}
```

This way, Spring will always be using the instance you have created.

Comment: So there is no way to do this without having to maintain our own component index?

Comment: @Nzall sorry, what do you mean by "component index"?

Comment: I mean that beyond annotating our services with @Service, this solution would also require us to have a class where we need to maintain a list (index) of all services we wish to instantiate in this manner. Forgetting to annotate a service is easy to detect since it breaks the application, not adding the service bean to this Configuration class doesn't break the application and as such is easy to forget. I was hoping for a solution where we wouldn't have to maintain such an index, either in a separate class or in our spring configuration XML file.

Comment: @Nzall not adding `@Bean` to `@Configuration` would still _break the application_ as Spring will have no way to `@Autowire` the instance..

Comment: @Nzall You are kinda fortunate that Spring can invoke a constructor regardless of visibility (your constructor is private). To me, it's better to maintain a configuration class than allow Spring to do things no one is allowed to do.

Comment: @Nzall "our web application currently has 2 instances of every singleton service: the singleton we created ourselves and the singleton created by Spring". It's weird, isn't? Why would Spring be allowed to create an instance of your "singleton"?

Comment: @riyaz-ali Hang on, so if there is an @ Configuration class, Spring will not autowire classes annotated with @ Service that do not also have an @ Bean annotated constructor in the @ Configuration class?

Comment: 1. As @AndrewTobilko said - Spring will create an instance of your class using the default, no-arg, private constructor
2. IMO, a custom `@Bean` annotation should only be used when you need to perform some initialization or Spring is (for some reason) unable to create an instance of your service class

Answer (score 0):

You can create add your singleton instance to spring container as bean from configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    @Bean
    public LevelApprovalServiceImpl service() {
        return LevelApprovalServiceImpl.getInstance();
    }
}
```

It would be right to choose either native singleton creation or Spring creation, btw your getInstance() is not thread-safe.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more on the thread safety? I don't quite understand how this is not thread-safe. This service does not have any state, so I'm not sure thread safety matters. All this service contains is service methods and a couple of private constants. This service should never change while active.

Comment: @Nzall you are absolutely right, my bad. I mixed up this singleton realization with another which should be supported synchronized keyword.